# Node.js cors request - Async example not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I am using the [node-cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) module in an app. I've followed some of their examples to make a cors request.

I have a route that I'd like to dynamically add cors options for:

```
var cors = require('cors'),
    user = require('../models/user');

router.get('/route', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res) {...}
```

**This works** (this comes straight from one of the examples):

```
var whitelist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com'];
var corsOptionsDelegate = function(req, callback){
  var corsOptions;
  if(whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1){
    corsOptions = { origin: true, credentials: true }; // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
  }else{
    corsOptions = { origin: false }; // disable CORS for this request
  }
  callback(null, corsOptions); // callback expects two parameters: error and options
};
```

This, however, **doesn't work** and I'm not sure what is wrong:

```
var corsOptions = function(req, callback){
  user.findOne({
        url: req.header('Origin')
    },function(err,match){
        var options;
        if(!empty(match)){
            options = {
                origin:true,
                credentials: true
            };
        }else{
            options = {
                origin: false,
                credentials: false
            };
        }
        callback(null, options);
  });
};
```

Is this an issue with the module, or something I've implemented wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say without debugging the issue.  Your callback likely is never getting called, but that's due to whatever your ORM is doing... and you didn't tell us what ORM you're using or how.  Make sure you're ending up in your ORM callback first, then make sure your callback for CORS is getting called.

Comment: @Brad I'm using Mongoose. What would cause the cors callback to fire before Mongoose's lookup callback, since one is wrapped inside the other?

Comment: I'm saying that your Mongoose callback may not be getting called... it's hard to say really though since no debugging is done.  Figure out where the specific issue is first, then come edit your question so we can help you better.

Answer (score -1):

You need to import this:
`const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});` instead of `const cors = require('cors');`